# Inner join Order

Tags: mysql, sql, teradata, proc

I have three tables- A, B, and C that each contain a list of active customers for 2012, 2013 and 2014, respecitvely.  I want to get a list of customers who were active in all three years.  I am doing it this way:

```
select distinct customer_id
from table_A a
inner join table_B b on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
inner join table_C c on a.customer_id=c.customer_id
```

But would that give different results than this:

```
select distinct customer_id
from table_A a
inner join table_B b on a.customer_id=b.customer_id
inner join table_C c on b.customer_id=c.customer_id
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of joins for `inner join` does not make a difference.

However, if one of the tables is a "master" table with one row per `customer_id`, then it is more efficient to do:

```
select a.customer_id
from table_A a
where exists (select 1 from table_B b where a.customer_id = b.customer_id) and
      exists (select 1 from table_C c on a.customer_id = c.customer_id);
```

This eliminates the duplicate reduction for the `select distinct`.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure if the order makes a difference.  Very much appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 1):

No, because you are doing an inner join.  Inner joins are an intersection, so only id's that are in all 3 are going to make it through, no matter what order you put the joins together.  If you do an outer join, you have to worry more about order.

Comment: Thank you!  I know this seems like a basic question and I could just try this myself, but this thought came to me at home, where I don't have access to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

No it should not be different result as inner join is an intersection.

Here is an example. "empid" 1 & 2 are the employees who have worked for all 3 years.

```
mysql> select * from t2012;
+-------+
| empid |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t2013;
+-------+
| empid |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
|     4 |
+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t2014;
+-------+
| empid |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     4 |
|     5 |

mysql> select distinct a.empid from t2012 a 
inner join t2013 b on a.empid = b.empid 
inner join t2014 c on a.empid=c.empid;
+-------+
| empid |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select distinct a.empid from t2012 a
 inner join t2013 b on a.empid = b.empid
 inner join t2014 c on b.empid=c.empid;
+-------+
| empid |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the customers which exist in all three tables you can use a set operation, too:

```
select customer_id from table_A
INTERSECT
select customer_id from table_B
INTERSECT
select customer_id from table_C
```

There's no explicit `DISTINCT`, but set operations default to it and the optimizer knows how to do it most efficiently.

Of course, depending on the actual data/indexes Gordon's answer using `EXISTS` might be faster.